# AWS dynamodb, table is getting deleted automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Created a table in AWS Dynamodb using AWS console in us-west-2 region. Table is getting automatically delete with no trace at all. To debug I enabled BAckup point in time recovery mode. I can see that there are backups of table which got deleted automatically by the system with $deletedTableBackup as a suffix.
Each time I create the table, I can pump data using access
_key and secrets.

Any help what's going on, what exactly is causing the issue. I am using a corporate account and I have the access to create/delete/modify table.

Comment: Check CloudTrial's Event history for API events related to dynamodb to identify who/what is deleting your tables.

Comment: Tables will not be being deleted automatically. Use cloud trail or contact aws support

Comment: Got it, Tables tags were not set, an automation script was deleting all Tables with invalid tags.